# How to highlight/indicate a link without mouseover?

Tags: hyperlink, highlight

I'm almost done with my new website and I figured I could do some improvements here and there before launching. One thing that bothers me is the fact that links are not underlined or highlighted in any way. It's okay, I want it that way. But I'm afraid certain links won't be noticed or might disappear completely next to more prominent features.

So I was wondering if there is a way to make the user notice the link without underlining/coloring/alternating it permanently. I was thinking of e.g. flashing an underscore/underline every 10 seconds (or randomly) or changing color every few seconds for a tiny bit. All without the need of the user's engagement (hovering over it). When you look at the page there should be some movement/change to help the user notice the link.

I hope you guys get what I mean. I am no expert by any means. If anyone could point me in the direction of any scripts/tutorials or whatever I'd be grateful. I tried googling around but couldn't come up with anything useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is bad, you should use hover for a better user experience, or add an underline by default to make the link more recognizable because most users will know this is a link.

Anyways if you want to do this, you will need javascript in your website.
You can try the following.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a")

setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i]
        
        link.classList.toggle("toggled")
    }
}, 1000)
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}

a.toggled {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<a href="#">This is a link!</a>
<p>Some text</p>
<a href="#">This is another link!</a>
```